# R - dataset from distinct groups - remove values according to group threshold

Tags: r

My question is fairly simple. Let's say I have a dataset like this:

```
'data.frame':   1200 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Subject  : Factor w/ 5 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ RT       : int  729 485 555 556 583 491 439 355 587 499 ...
```

Where RT stand for reaction times. I would like to filter out RTs that are above/below the mean +/- 2 S.D., but the mean and SD I need to compute it for each subject, and apply the filter for data from each subject separately. I guess I could simply subset my dataset, make the operations, and then concatenate the data to get all my subjects together, but I was wondering if there would be a more efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df2)[, .SD[RT <= (mean(RT)+2*sd(RT)) &
      RT >= (mean(RT)-2*sd(RT)) ], by=Subject]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Akrun, looks like an interesting alternative, but for some reason is not filtering my data, it keeps giving me the same data frame,

Comment: @user3274394  YOu haven't showed a reproducible example.  Based on the description only, I was coding.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it, instead of mean(RT) is just RT....                         setDT(df2)[, .SD[ RT <= (mean(RT)+2*sd(RT)) & RT >= (mean(RT)-2*sd(RT)) ], by=Subject]

Comment: @user3274394  Updated the code.  I thought you want to remove the groups that doesn't meet the condition.

Comment: Nop, it was always about filtering the RTs values. It helps me anyway. Thanks.